# arbitrarily app get crash during sending of image from gallery to server

Tags: android, soap

I am sending an image from gallery to server using soap web service. Most times the send is successful but sometimes the application crashes and shows the message `Unfortunately application has stopped`.

Comment: Without logcat how can we help you??

Comment: This is logcat error

Comment: This is logcat error(i am using sending file  during video conferencing)     
12-24 18:39:26.396: E/AndroidRuntime(2654): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rank.insurance.vidyosample/rank.insurance.activity.SuppotActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
12-24 18:39:26.396: E/AndroidRuntime(2654):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java

Comment: Not in a comment please.  Edit your question, include the **full** stack trace, and format it correctly.